# How to get errors captured from nifi logs specific to my application when multiple nifi applications are running

Tags: apache-nifi

We have multiple team nifi applications running in same nifi machine... Is there any way to log the logs specific to my application? Also by default nifi-app.log file is difficult to track the issues and bulletin board shows the error msg for only 5 mins... How to get the errors captured and send an mail alert in Nifi?

Please help me to get through this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have 2 questions here. If you have multiple questions please create a separate post for each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parsing the nifi log, you can separate the logs which is specific to your team applications, by using the processor group id and using Nifi Rest API. Check the below link for the nifi template and python codes to solve this issue:

https://link.medium.com/L6IY1wTimV

Comment: Thanks Karthi keyan..I will import this template and check this in my nifi machine and let you know

Comment: It works specific to my team application... I gave the root processor group, and able to track the logs related to all the processors inside my application, but we have controller service also, for that I think we need to use one more rest API to track the controller service also...
Thanks a lot Karthik

Comment: Good to know. Yes, to track the controller services, you need to use the below rest api in existing python code in that give template.

`http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller-services/{id}`

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to approach this. One is to route failure relationships from processors to a `PutEmail` processor which can send an alert on errors. Another is to use a custom reporting task to alert a monitoring service when a certain number of flowfiles are in an error queue.

Finally, we have heard that in multitenant environments, log parsing is difficult. While NiFi aims to reduce or completely eliminate the need to visually inspect logs by providing the data provenance feature, in the event you do need to inspect the logs, we recommend searching the log by processor ID to isolate relevant messages. You can also use NiFi itself to ingest those same logs and perform parsing and filtering activities if desired. Future versions may improve this experience.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the response.

We use PutEmail. There are multiple fail over scenarios so, in each place we are using this mail processor. Like if we 200 processor , around 40 processor is putEmail processor...

Comment: Is there an opportunity to combine those into a single `PutEmail` with parameterized values?

Comment: Again, to parameterize the putEmail, we have to use 40 update attribute or any other processor to parameterize the input (body of mail in putEmail)

Comment: I guess if every message must be unique, but I think with Expression Language there is probably an opportunity to decrease that number. You may need to engage a vendor for professional services engagement.

Answer (score 0):

You can send all the errors in a Processor Group to the same processor, it could be a regular UpdateAttribute or a custom processor, this processor is going to add the path and all the relevant information and then send this to a general error/logs flow that is going to check the information inside the flowfile regarding to the error, and will make the decision of send or not an email, to whom and this kind of things.
Using this approach, the system keeps simple and inside NiFi, so you don't add more layers of complexity, and you are going to have only one processor to manage the errors per Process Group.

This is the way we are managing errors in my company.